# How to disable input in bound combobox using IME

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, ime

I am trying to find a way to disable IME input (Japanese) in a bound combobox control in MS access 2016 form.

The problem I am facing is that on a **bound** ComboBox control it will change to **Hiragana** even with `IME mode` set to `disable`, whilst on a **non bound** Combobox, setting `IME mode` to `disable` will prevent IME from changing to **Hiragana** which is the expected behavior.

My ultimate goal is to disable all kind of keyboard input to the target ComboBox either bound or unbound either with direct input or with IME.

I use the following code the block keyboard input (non IME) in the ComboBox, but this does not work with IME input, so I thought disabling IME is my only way achieve complete keyboard input prevention on the control.

```vb
Private Sub comboBox_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
  If KeyCode <> vbKeyTab And KeyCode <> vbKeyReturn And KeyCode <> vbKeyDelete And KeyCode <> vbKeyBack Then KeyCode = 0
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

By **bound** control, I mean it has the property `Control Source` set

Comment: How do you set control IMEMode to disable? Perhaps use Off instead of Disable setting. Review https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother-mso_2007/access-what-is-ime-mode/9006cf84-86ca-40e2-926a-ebea52efa76b

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Setting it to `Off` will allow the activation of Japanese from inside the control. but setting it to `Disable` I can't activate Japanese IME from Unbound Control.